# display the id of div in which the list is present

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<div id="a" style="background-color:green;">
 <ul>
  <li>abc</li>
   <ul>
    <li>def</li>
   </ul>
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="b" style="background-color:red">
 <ul>
  <li>ghi</li>
   <ul>
    <li>jkl</li>
   </ul>
 </ul>
</div>
<select>
 <option>abc</option>
 <option>def</option>
 <option>ghi</option>
 <option>jkl</option>
</select>
<span display=""></span>
<input type="button" value="click" />
```

This is my HTML code. It consist of two divs a and b. a and b div consist of li elements. Whatever, I choose in dropdown and click the button it must show the id of div in which the li is present using JQuery.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery, provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can *filter* through the lists and check for the *selected text* in the dropdown and find the `div` which contains the list - see demo below:

```js
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
  let selected = $('select').val();
  console.log(
    $('#a, #b').find('li').filter(function() {
      return selected === $(this).text()
    }).closest('div').attr('id')
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a" style="background-color:green;">
  <ul>
    <li>abc</li>
    <ul>
      <li>def</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="b" style="background-color:red">
  <ul>
    <li>ghi</li>
    <ul>
      <li>jkl</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<select>
  <option>abc</option>
  <option>def</option>
  <option>ghi</option>
  <option>jkl</option>
</select>
<span display=""></span>
<input type="button" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two separate arrays and push values of both arrays in it and find the selected dropdown value in it.

Please check below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var aLis = [];
  $("#a li").each(function(){
    aLis.push($(this).text());
  });
  var bLis = [];
  $("#b li").each(function(){
    bLis.push($(this).text());
  });
  
  $("input[type='button']").on("click",function(){
    var selected = $("select").val();
    if($.inArray(selected,aLis) !== -1){
      console.log("Selected value is in div with ID 'a'");
    }else if($.inArray(selected,bLis) !== -1){
      console.log("Selected value is in div with ID 'b'");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a" style="background-color:green;">
  <ul>
    <li>abc</li>
    <ul>
      <li>def</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="b" style="background-color:red">
  <ul>
    <li>ghi</li>
    <ul>
      <li>jkl</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<select>
  <option>abc</option>
  <option>def</option>
  <option>ghi</option>
  <option>jkl</option>
</select>
<span display=""></span>
<input type="button" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input:button").click(function() {


  var text = $("select option:selected").text();
  var display = $("div ul li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == text;
  }).closest("div").attr("id")
  $("span").text(display)
  console.log(display)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" style="background-color:green;">
  <ul>
    <li>abc</li>
    <ul>
      <li>def</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="b" style="background-color:red">
  <ul>
    <li>ghi</li>
    <ul>
      <li>jkl</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<select>
  <option>abc</option>
  <option>def</option>
  <option>ghi</option>
  <option>jkl</option>
</select>
<span display=""></span>
<input type="button" value="click" />
```

Use filter to compare the text of li to current selected option then get its closest div attr id

Answer (score 0):

You only need to get the value of the dropdown on button click and then loop through each `li` comparing the text value and then just find the `parent div` of the `li` where the text matches

```js
$(function(){
 $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
   var cal = $('select').val();
    $('li').each(function(index, item) {
      console.log($(item).text(), cal);
     if(($(item).text().trim() == cal)){
       alert($(item).closest('div').attr('id'));
      }
    })
  
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" style="background-color:green;">
 <ul>
  <li>abc</li>
   <ul>
    <li>def</li>
   </ul>
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="b" style="background-color:red">
 <ul>
  <li>ghi</li>
   <ul>
    <li>jkl</li>
   </ul>
 </ul>
</div>
<select>
 <option>abc</option>
 <option>def</option>
 <option>ghi</option>
 <option>jkl</option>
</select>
<span display=""></span>
<input type="button" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find selected li using `:contains` and then get the `div`.

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click",function(){
 var x=$( "li:contains('"+$("select").val()+"')" ).closest("div").get(0).id;
 console.log(x); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a" style="background-color:green;">
 <ul>
  <li>abc</li>
   <ul>
    <li>def</li>
   </ul>
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="b" style="background-color:red">
 <ul>
  <li>ghi</li>
   <ul>
    <li>jkl</li>
   </ul>
 </ul>
</div>
<select>
 <option>abc</option>
 <option>def</option>
 <option>ghi</option>
 <option>jkl</option>
</select>
<span display=""></span>
<input type="button" value="click" />
```